# how to update the plist file in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, plist, nsdictionary

I am developing one application.In that i am trying to update the plist  file using below code.

```
 plist_path=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Configurationfile" ofType:@"plist"];
 config_dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:plist_path];
[config_dict setValue:textField.text forKey:@"ServerURL"];
NSLog(@"%@",config_dict);
[config_dict writeToFile:plist_path atomically:YES];
[config_dict release];
```

But it's not working.But NSlog showing the correct values for every key in the dictionary.Please help me how to update the plist file.

Comment: Euh. First time I've encountered this error, I've googled the syndromes, and there were plenty of hits as to why this is not working. This has also been asked hundreds of times on StackOverflow. I can't believe you just couldn't fine one dupe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone write to file fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386973/iphone-write-to-file-fails) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155952/iphone-writetofile-not-saving-new-entry-into-plist/3156393#3156393) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368752/modifying-a-plist-is-not-working) and ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update the files within the app bundle.  Instead copy the files to a working directory and update them there.