# Writing to mainBundle plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, nsdictionary

i have a question i created a plist of movies.
Root is of type Dictionary
and Pixar type Array
 with 3 string movie titles 
I am able to read from the list with the following code no problem

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movies" ofType:@"plist"];

NSMutableDictionary *movies =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

from here i can print the list no problem.
I want to add another movie to this list now.
so i transfered the list to a array and then saved the array back to the file but its not working.
any idea of where i went wrong?

```
NSMutableArray *array= [movies valueForKey:@"Pixar"];
NSString *incredible=@"Incredibles";
[array addObject:incredible];

[movies setObject:array forKey:@"Pixar"];

[movies writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: You went wrong when you didn't search for this. Duplicate **a lot of times.**

Comment: i have been looking for a bit now if you see it please send me the link instead of just saying duplicate

Comment: possible duplicate of [modifying a plist is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368752/modifying-a-plist-is-not-working) **and** [how to update plist file in ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870092/how-to-update-the-plist-file-in-ios) **and** [iphone write to file fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386973/iphone-write-to-file-fails) -- what's so hard in searching?

Comment: I think you can not write to main bundle only read..if this is wrong please correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot, on the device, write to the bundle. The simulator doesn't enforce these constraints, but the device will.

One approach is to:

1. See if the file exists in the `Documents` folder.
2. If it does, read it from the `Documents` folder. If not, read it from the bundle.
3. When done adding/removing records, write the file to the `Documents` folder.

Thus:

```
NSString *bundlePath    = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movies" ofType:@"plist"];
NSString *docsFolder    = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *documentsPath = [docsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Movies.plist"];

NSMutableDictionary *movies = nil;

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentsPath])
    movies = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:documentsPath];

if (!movies)
    movies = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:bundlePath];

// do whatever edits you want

[movies writeToFile:documentsPath atomically:YES];
```